# python group on 2 keys in a list of lists and sum on 2 different values in each list

Tags: python, group-by, sum

Given a list of lists:

```
d = [['a', 'x', 10.5, 5 ],['a', 'x',  6.5, 4 ],['b', 'x',  4.0, 3 ],['b', 'x',  2.0, 2 ],['b', 'z',  5.5, 4 ]];
```

I have tried:

```
for key, rows in groupby(data, lambda x: (x[0], x[1])): 
        print (key, sum (r[2] for r in rows), sum (r[2] for r in rows) )
```

But get:

```
('a', 'x') 17.0 0
('b', 'x') 6.0 0
('b', 'z') 5.5 0
```

How do I get a list of lists that is grouped on the 1st 2 elements and Summed on each of the last 2 float and int to get:

```
[['a', 'x', 17.0, 9], ['b', 'x', 6.0 , 5],['b', 'z', 5.5 , 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store the iterator returned by [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) so that you can iterate over it multiple times:

```
from itertools import groupby

d = [['a', 'x', 10.5, 5 ],['a', 'x',  6.5, 4 ],['b', 'x',  4.0, 3 ],
     ['b', 'x',  2.0, 2 ],['b', 'z',  5.5, 4 ]]

for key, rows in groupby(d, lambda x: (x[0], x[1])):
    rows = tuple(rows)
    print (key, sum (r[2] for r in rows), sum(r[3] for r in rows))
```

Output:

```
(('a', 'x'), 17.0, 9)
(('b', 'x'), 6.0, 5)
(('b', 'z'), 5.5, 4)
```

`groupby` yields `(key, iterator)` tuples and the iterator can be only iterated over once. Your code tries to do that twice thus on the second try there are no items left and `sum` results to `0`.

Of course you could just use list comprehension which would allow you to skip the storing part:

```
[reduce(lambda x,y: k + map(sum, zip(x[2:],y[2:])), g) 
 for k, g in groupby(d, lambda x: x[:2])]

# [['a', 'x', 17.0, 9], ['b', 'x', 6.0, 5], ['b', 'z', 5.5, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with list comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby

[k + [sum(r) for i, r in enumerate(zip(*g)) if i >= 2] for k, g in groupby(d, key = lambda x: x[:2])]

# [['a', 'x', 17.0, 9], ['b', 'x', 6.0, 5], ['b', 'z', 5.5, 4]]
```

Comment: Why not `lambda x: x[:2]`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Ah, yes. Even a shorter syntax.